# Single url variable with multiple values into array

Tags: php, arrays, variables, urlvariables

I have a url with a single variable (category), but the variable has multiple values.

Example: http://websiteurl.com/?category=cat+dog+rabbit+-cow

I'd like to generate an array with this information.

```
    <?$category[] = $_GET['category'];?>
```

print_r reveals this:

```
    $category = Array ( [0] => cat dog rabbit -cow )
```

Here's what I need that to look like:

```
    $category = array('cat','dog','rabbit','-cow');
```

Comment: http://php.net/explode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried...

```
$categories = explode(' ', $_GET['category']);
```